# These functions are very similar. Is there an explanation?

Tags: logarithms, special-functions, gamma-function

Blue: $x \ln x-x$

Brown: $\ln \frac{\Gamma(x+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

[image]

Comment: Compare with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). See also [DLMF eq. 5.11.](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#E1).

Comment: As a minor amplification of the above: For positive $z$, the agreement improves further if one uses $\sqrt{2\pi}$ rather than $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I tried to make it symmetric so that both positive and negative matched (and zero). Possibly, the brown function needs to be stretched horizontally a bit.

Answer (score 9):

Using Sterling’s approximation for the Gamma function, $$\Gamma(z)\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z$$
In this case \begin{align*}
\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)&\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{x+\frac{1}{2}}}\left(\frac{x+\frac{1}{2}}{e}\right)^{x+\frac{1}{2}}\\
\ln\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)&\sim \frac{1}{2}\ln 2+\ln \sqrt \pi -\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-x-\frac{1}{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\ln 2+\ln \sqrt \pi +x\ln \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)-x-\frac{1}{2}\\
&\sim \ln \sqrt\pi +x\ln x-x\\
\ln \left(\frac{\Gamma\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt\pi}\right)&\sim x\ln x-x
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Well, I post my own answer. The real reason is that (up to some constant terms and factors), the first function is $D^{-1}D^{-1}[\frac1x]$ and the second function is $D^{-1}\Delta^{-1}[\frac1x]$. So, in one case we replace one normal integration operator with discrete integration. There is no surprise, the functions should be similar.